# Returning a tree as a string in InOrder sequence

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, inorder

I must write a function which takes in an tree as an argument and returns it as a string in inorder sequence.

This is what I got.

```
public static String concatInOrder( StringTreeNode t )
    {

        if(t == null) return "";

        return (t.left+t.val+t.right); 
    }
```

However I've ran into several difficulties with this. Several questions.

1. Am I approaching the problem wrongly?
2. How may I improve my prowess when it comes to Binary Search tree manipulation WITHOUT the use of libraries and such?
3. What Am I missing? Isn't it true that inOrder sequence is left, current, right?  (val is short for value, so the leaf it's currently on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that's the correct order. The [`inorder`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/inorder/info) tag you added says that much.

You need to recursively call the `concatInOrder` method:

```
public static String concatInOrder(StringTreeNode t)
{
    if (t == null) return "";

    return concatInOrder(t.left) + t.val + concatInOrder(t.right);
}
```

Comment: Thank you (Both of you) for answering my question! I will accept your answer when I can. ( There's a limit of it).